# Error while creating Journey through REST API JSON

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using the following REST endpoint to create a journey

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions

This journey has multiple email sends and wait times.I have retrieved the JSON through a GET call.

I have done this in the past as well.
But now I am getting the below error.
Is anyone aware of any recent changes?

Error Message:

```
{
    "message": "InteractionStudio currently only supports configuring 1 Event activity at this time.",
    "errorcode": 10003,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Update:I am no longer getting this error.I was able to create a Journey with a REST POST call from a JSON.